# Почему this стрелочных функций не зависит от контекста вызова?

Tags: javascript, функции, ecmascript-6, this

Вопрос: Почему у стрелочных функций `this` не зависит от контекста вызова?

```js
const x = {
  y: () => console.log(this),
  z: function() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}
```

При вызове `x.y()` вернет `window`, а не `x`, почему так устроено?

Comment: Стрелочные функции не для короткого синтаксиса созданы. Короткая запись  лишь дополнительная плюшка, которая может выстрелить в ногу, если не знать, что суть стрелочных функций в отсутствии собственного this

Answer (score 6):

Выражения стрелочных функций имеют более короткий синтаксис по сравнению с функциональными выражениями и лексически привязаны к значению `this` (но не привязаны к собственному `this`, `arguments`, `super`, или `new.target`). Стрелочные функции всегда анонимные[[источник]](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Простым языком — стрелочные функции не имеют собственного `this`.

> UPD [Хорошая статья](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/428566/).
>
> UPD2 Стрелочная функция — обёртка. Реализация стрелочной функции(Запустите в консоле **БРОУЗЕРА**!):

```js
const data = 1;

function strelka() {
  console.log(this);
}

strelka.call(data);
// Аналогично
strelka.apply(data);
```

Аналогично:

```js
const data = 1;

(function() {
  console.log(this);
}).call(data);

(function () {
  console.log(this);
}).apply(data);
```

Comment: Я знаю это, у меня на собесе был вопрос: "Почему нет this у стрелочной функции".=)

Comment: @ПавелТонкович, и  что вы ответили? Мой ответ помог вам, если да, отметте его как верный.

Comment: к сожалению не помог. Вопрос был не как работает стрелка, а в её устройстве. Почему у них не this, а у обычных функций есть =(

Comment: @ПавелТонкович, так потому, что она так реализована в ES6.

Comment: в этом и вопрос - Как так реализована?

Comment: @ПавелТонкович подправил.

Comment: Статья про анонимность устарела давным давно.

Comment: @Qwertiy поделитесь ссылкой на текущие дела.

Comment: @doox911, ссылку искать надо, но вот скриншот из консоли бораузера: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SpiH.png. Ну и там же видно, что и обычные функции не настолько анонимны, как это написано при переходе по ссылке на анонимность функций.

Comment: О, насчёт ссылки: [kangax](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) указывает на спецификацию ES6, а именно [сюда](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname).

Answer (score -1):

Для тех кому интересно, стрелочная функция - это анонимная функция обертка(АФО) и при простом вызове из любого места АФО контекст вызова `this` равен `window`. Но стрелочная функция дополнительно автоматически привязывает к себе текущий контекст вызова и возможно из-за этого на нее не распространяется попытка привязки контекста из вне(не работают методы `bind`,`call`,`apply`). Это мое мысли, примерная реализация стрелочной функции ниже. Поправьте если что.

```
let obj = {
    getThisOne: function () {
        return () => this;
    },
    getThisTwo: function () {
        return (function() {
            return this;
        }).bind(this);
    },
}
```

**@doox911** подтолкнул на ответ, но не ответил в полной мере. Спасибо за помощь, я помечу Ваш ответ как "Полезный".